# Struggling to understand algebraic number theory proof

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm struggling to understand a small part of proof I'm reading on.

Let $b_1,...,b_d$ be a basis of the field $K$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of algebraic integers.

$O_K:=\{\alpha\in K|\alpha$ is algebraic$\}$

Let $H$ be an additive subgroup generated by the $b_i$ and let $Q=O_K/H$, then $Q$ is a finite group(does this mean that the size of $Q$ is finite or it's finitely generated) and $|Q|^2$ divides $\triangle_K(b_1,...,b_d)$.

How do we arrive at this result, I don't see any relation between $\triangle_K(b_1,...,b_d)$ and $|Q|^2$

Comment: Also is there anything to suggest that $|Q|$ is a prime number

Comment: Those $\;b_i\;$ are a basis of $\;K\;$ ... *over what* ??

Comment: over $\mathbb{Z}$, I'll edit my question to add that.

Comment: As far as I know, fields are considered vector spaces over *subfields*, not merely over sub rings. Perhaps it should be over the rationals $\;\Bbb Q\;$ ? But then I don't understand the definition of $\;O_K\;$ , which should be, imo, the maximal order in $\;K\;$ , if I recall correctly the standard definitions.

Comment: The proof doesn't really mention what it's a basis over, but I guess it's over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: But then $\;K/\Bbb Q\;$ is an algebraic extension, and thus $\;O_K=K\;$ ...If your notation is more or less standard, you are dealing with discriminant of a number field and stuff, and then basic things as the above ones should be already well known. Please try to read correctly the problem and post it correctly, too.

Comment: I expect $O_K$ should denote the set of algebraic integers in $K$. Then all of the statements are standard results.